# NativeScript says no emulator images found?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, nativescript

So its my first time using native script and I can't seem to get it to recognise any of the emulators? I also downloaded NativeScript and its saying that I am also missing emulators.

Running `tns device android --available-devices` returns

```
Available emulators
┌─────────────┬──────────┬─────────┬───────────────────┬──────────────────┬────────────┐
│ Device Name │ Platform │ Version │ Device Identifier │ Image Identifier │ Error Help │
└─────────────┴──────────┴─────────┴───────────────────┴──────────────────┴────────────┘

Connected devices & emulators
Searching for devices...
Cannot find connected devices. Reconnect any connected devices, verify that your system recognizes them, and run this command again.
```

On Sidekick, I want to use cloud build because I'm on windows and can't have xcode, but that also tells me that it can't find any devices?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eeu8H.png

When clicking 'Virtual Device Launcher' button, it just tells me no emulator images were found?

Comment: Did you download emulators via Android Studio -> AVD Manager? Are you able to start the emulator from Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Run `Command Prompt` as Administrator and execute :

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://nativescript.org/setup/win-avd'))"
```

This should download/fix Android AVDs on your Windows system.